# How to use React Router to route to another url AND re-render page with NEW component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In App.js, I have a button that if you click, should redirect users using React-Route to another URL, `/landingpagehahaha`, and should render a component called `LandingPage`. However, neither the URL is being changed in my browser nor the correct component being rendered. The behavior right now when you click the button is that the current page gets re-rendered, not the correct `LandingPage` component.

The React-Route logic is placed in a function called `routeChange()`. I put 2 alert() statements in it which get called, telling me that it is getting inside that function. However, nothing else changes.

I have tried using `this.props.history.push("./LandingPage");` in `routeChange()` but it doesn't get past that statement. It appears like it behaves like `response.json()`, which returns from the function after it runs.

I have also tried using `withRouter()`, but I get a weird error that I can't call `Route` inside `Router`. I was unable to resolve that issue.

```
// Changes route
  routeChange() {
    alert("HELLO BEFORE");
    alert("HELLo");
    return (
      <div>
        <Route path="/landingpagehahaha" component={LandingPage} />;
      </div>
    );
  }
```

```
// The button that is supposed to bring user to next page
<button onClick={this.routeChange}>Go To Next Page</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the Redirect component from your render function, or as use the history api to push the route into your navigation stack.
The first thing you should do, is move out the route declaration, and play it higher up in your component hierachy, you have to make sure the route declaration is rendered, when you're trying to go to the route.
Instead of using the history api, you could also use the Redirect component provided by react-router. I've made a small example here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-paper-kxcri

Comment: I give correct answer to you because no one else answered, but I ended up resolving my issue following this Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Law7wfdg_ls. Thanks for answering! :)